# How to change selection fields with filters search in odoo? [Odoo 9]

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-9

I have created a state on models

```
state = fields.Selection([
        ('new', 'New'),
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('approved', 'Approved')
        ],default='new')
```

I make menuitems that are different for user and admin. But in the admin groups, i get an error after adding filters search.

```
<record id="view_admin_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Admin</field>
    <field name="model">mymodels</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Admin">
             <filter string="Draft" name="state" domain="[('state','=','draft')]"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

and

```
<record id="open_module_tree_admin" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Admin</field>
    <field name="res_model">mymodels</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="context">{
            "search_default_state": 1,
            "default_state": 1}
        </field>
        <field name="domain">[]</field>
        <field name="view_ids" eval="[(5, 0, 0),
            (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'tree', 'view_id': ref('view_admin_tree')}),
            (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'form', 'view_id': ref('view_admin_form')})]"/>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_admin_filter"/>
        <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Click to create.
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

I found an error like this

```
ValueError: Wrong value for mail.mail.state: 1
```

I have tried to replace it like this

```
"search_default_state": 'draft',
"default_state": 'draft'}
```

but it still doesn't work and getting error

```
ValueError: Wrong value for mail.mail.state: u'draft'
```

how should I fix it?

Comment: Can you put the definition of your model. `_name,  _inherit` and when do you get the error exactly when you try to apply the filter, when you open view or click on create?

Comment: @Cherif in my model `_name = "mymodels", _inherit = ['mail.thread']`. I get an error when create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you said you are setting a default value for state some where in your code
with a value that is not in selection.

like for example when you did this:

```
   "default_state": 1
```

This will cause this error to happen because I'm sure that `1` is not valid value
instead doing this is correct.

```
  "default_state": 'draft'
```

But only if your selection has this value 'draft'.

One thing you should know in `XML` removing the code of the context from the action
definition will not remove it from the data base (you will keep having the same problem).

To fix this problem remove this default values from your code then do it again step by step
and make sure you upgrade the moduel and restart the server.

```xml
    <record id="open_module_tree_admin" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Admin</field>
        <field name="res_model">mymodels</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="context">{}</field>   <!-- this will update the context to {} -->
        .....
        ....
```

and check your python code for default value or onchange event make sure your not setting
the state field to a wrong value.

```py
  fields.Selection(.... default='draft')
```

Hope this helps you

And for your filter don't give them names like your fields names

```xml
  <filter string="Draft" name="draft_state" domain="[('state','=','draft')]"/>
```

This way you can apply this filter in the context of the action like this:*

```
  {'search_default_draft_state': 1}
```

I think it's safer.

Comment: I changed fields name from filters. This is worked. Thanks for your suggest code.